# sympy: substitution of expressions with Braket-notation

Tags: sympy, quantum-computing

I am using sympy (in sagemath). I would like to do a substitution, with Braket-notation (for quantum mechanical problem). Below there is a minimalistic code, in order to reproduce the problem.

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import Bra, Ket
from sympy import *
theta=symbols('theta',commutative=True)
pi, mu= symbols("pi mu",commutative=False)
W=2*pi*mu
print(W.subs(pi*mu,theta))
V=Bra(pi)*Ket(mu)
print(V.subs(Bra(pi)*Ket(mu),theta))
U=2*Bra(pi)*Ket(mu)
print(U.subs(Bra(pi)*Ket(mu),theta))
```

The output is:

```
2*theta
theta
2*<pi|*|mu>
```

If there is no leading scalar multiplier, the substitution works finely. I am stuck with a more complicated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these occasions `srepr` can shed some light:

```
srepr(U)
# out: "Mul(Integer(2), Bra(Symbol('pi', commutative=False)), Ket(Symbol('mu', commutative=False)))"

srepr(Bra(pi)*Ket(mu))
# out: "InnerProduct(Bra(Symbol('pi', commutative=False)),Ket(Symbol('mu', commutative=False)))"
```

Note that the first output is a multiplication, object of type `Mul`, whereas the second output is an object of type `InnerProduct`. With the command `U.subs(Bra(pi)*Ket(mu),theta)` you are asking to search for an object of type `InnerProduct` into `U`, but there is none, hence no substitution has been done.

In this case, you have to do:

```
U.subs(Mul(Bra(pi), Ket(mu)),theta)
# out: 2*theta
```

Edit: or as @Oscar Benjamin pointed out, you do:

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply
U = qapply(U)
srepr(U)
# out: "Mul(Integer(2), InnerProduct(Bra(Symbol('pi', commutative=False)),Ket(Symbol('mu', commutative=False))))"
```

Now you can see an `InnerProduct` as an argument of `Mul`. FInally:

```
U.subs(Bra(pi)*Ket(mu), theta)
# out: 2*theta
```

Comment: Also `qapply(U)` will canonicalise the `Mul` to an `InnerProduct`.